# Why is the mesh deforming?

Tags: animation

When rigging this gun for some reason the trigger doesn't seem to response the way I intended? Why does it seem like its rotating the bottom of the trigger, and how can I fix this?
I have separated everything into vertex groups and all vertices seem to be selected I'm not sure why it's doing this.

[image: Before Rotation]

[image: After Rotation]

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!!!
It was because I had an edge selected in my root vertex group I had to deselect it from that group for it to work properly.